# Using CMHeadphoneMotionManager in independent WatchOS app to Access AirPods Pro Accelerometer Data

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, core-motion

I'm working on an independent application for WatchOS (without the iOS companion app) where I aim to utilise the accelerometer data from my AirPods Pro. I'm using CMHeadphoneMotionManager for this purpose. However, I'm encountering an issue where I don't receive any updates and the isDeviceMotionAvailable property returns false. This issue only occurs when I run my code WatchOS; it operates as expected on iOS demo app.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
let motionManager = CMHeadphoneMotionManager()

func startMotionUpdates() {
    if motionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: .main) { (motion, error) in
            // Process motion data
        }
    } else {
        print("Device motion updates are not available.")
    }
}
```

I expected to receive motion updates in the WatchOS app similar to the iOS app, but the isDeviceMotionAvailable is always false, and the updates are not being received.
I found a similar query on the Apple forum, so someone else also has this problem.
Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix it?